# WPF Add trigger to an existing style from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `TabControl` with some tabs declared in XAML. I want to add new tabs and bind their `IsEnabled` properties to some properties of their content:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < context.Pictures.Count; ++i)
    {
        var tabItem = new TabItem();
        var title = "Some title"
        tabItem.Header = title;
        var image = new Image();
        Binding sourceBinding = new Binding(nameof(context.Pictures) + $"[{i}]");
        sourceBinding.Source = context;
        image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, sourceBinding);
        image.Width = 800;
        image.Height = 600;
        
        DataTrigger isEnabledTrigger = new DataTrigger() { Binding = sourceBinding, Value = null };
        isEnabledTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.IsEnabledProperty, false));

        tabItem.Content = image;
        tabControl.Items.Add(tabItem);
    }
```

I want to disable tab if the picture inside is `null` (apply `isEnabledTrigger`). Problem here is that style of `tabItem` is derived from `tabControl` containing it, so I cannot just create a style with my trigger and apply it to `TabItem`. Sure, I could just copy original style and hardcode it, but I don't think it's a good way to solve my problem.

So, to solve my problem I have two ideas:

1. Create a shallow copy of existing style, add trigger and apply it
2. Load original style from XAML, add trigger and apply it (may be difficult, since it lies in another project)

Is there more rational way to bind `TabControl`s `IsEnabled` to contained `Image`s value?

Comment: The correct approach would be to define a `DataTemplate`  for the tab content  and assign it to `TabControl.ContentTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add `TabItem` directly. Use data models. This is recommended approach for all item controls. Then define a `DataTemplate` for the data model(s) and assign it to `TabControl.ContentTemplate`.
Use the `TabControl.ItemTemplate` to layout the header.
Defining a `Style` for the `TabControl.ItemContainerStyle` allows you to set up the required triggers quite easily. Doing layout using C# is never a good idea. Always use XAML.

See: [Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview), [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0)

The minimal model class should look like this:

**PictureModel.cs**

```
// All binding source models must implement INotifyPropertyChanged
public class PictureModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string title;
  public string Title
  {
    get => this.title;
    set
    {
      this.title = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private string source;
  public string Source
  {
    get => this.source;
    set
    {
      this.source = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<PictureModel> Pictures { get; }

  private void CreateTabItems(Context context)
  {
    foreach (string imageSource in context.Pictures)
    {
      var pictureModel = new PictureModel() 
      {
        Title = "Some Title",
        Source = imageSource
      };
      this.Pictures.Add(pictureModel);
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

    <!-- Layout the tab content -->
  <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:PictureModel}">
        <Image Source="{Binding Source}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

    <!-- Layout the tab header -->
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:PictureModel}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

    <!-- Setup triggers. The DataContext is the current data model -->
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
  </TabControl>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should base your `Style` on the current `Style`:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(TabItem))
{
    BasedOn = FindResource(typeof(TabItem)) as Style
};
DataTrigger isEnabledTrigger = new DataTrigger() { Binding = sourceBinding, Value = null };
isEnabledTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(TabItem.IsEnabledProperty, false));
style.Triggers.Add(isEnabledTrigger);
tabItem.Style = style;
```

Or

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(TabItem))
{
    BasedOn = tabControl.ItemContainerStyle
};
...
```

...depending on how your current `Style` is applied.

This is how you would extend an existing `Style` with your `DataTrigger` and this is a good way of solving this.